# Could someone help me to understand difference between static queue and dynamic queue?

Tags: activemq-classic, message-queue, ibm-mq

While I was working on the Message-Queue, I encounter the word **static queue** and **dynamic queue**.
Can any one tell me the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A static queue is one that is defined ahead of time and the queue definition persists in the environment.

A dynamic queue is created on demand.  Of these there are two varieties in IBM MQ.  A temporary dynamic queue is created on demand and is deleted when the program that created it disconnects.  A permanent dynamic queue is one that is created on demand but persists in the environment after the program which created it disconnects.

For example, a temporary dynamic queue is useful for catching replies in a request/reply scenario.  The queue exists only so long as the application making requests is connected.  When the program disconnects, the queue goes away so there is no need for the administrator to manually clean it up.

A permanent dynamic queue is useful for things like durable subscriptions.  When a subscription is created, the queue needs to be unique and the overhead of having to define it ahead of time is excessive.  So we let the application create it dynamically but also let the queue hang around when the program is offline in order to collect publications.  Normally, the application deletes the queue when it is no longer needed so that the administrator doesn't need to.

Comment: Thanks Rob. One more thing, can you explain temporary/permanent dynamic queue.

Comment: Read the answer again.

Comment: @Rob, I am asking in terms of example.

Comment: Thanks Rob, that's the answer I am looking for. :)

Comment: Thank you @Rob, could you please explain what is the difference between static queue and permanent dynamic queue, in which case should i use a static queue?